# transparent screen lock in gnome-shell using Wayland

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I would like to create something like a transparent screen lock for `gnome-shell` using Wayland.

I was already playing with gnome-extensions and looking at the API: https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html

But before starting this journey, I would like to know **how are the chances of succeeding?**
I've seen that gnome-shell does not support `ext-session-lock-v1`.

Maybe another solution would be to lock keyboard and mouse input.

Hopefully someone "knowing" could point me into the right direction.

Thank You!